# How to calculate this integration about normal distribution?

Tags: integration, logarithms, normal-distribution

I want to solve a integration of the following expression:
$$
\log{T}
 = \int_t^{t+T}
     \log \left[ 1 - \frac{1}{\sigma_{\tau} \sqrt{2\pi}}
                     \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma_{\tau}^2}\right)\right]
   \mathrm{d}x
$$
where $t$, $T$, $\sigma_{\tau}$ are constants, and $x$ is the variable.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT** If you integrate by parts, letting $u = \ln(1-f(x))$ so $du = \dfrac{-f'(x)}{1-f(x)}$ and $dv = dx \implies v = x$ you get
$$
\int \ln(1-f(x))dx = \int udv = uv - \int vdu = x\ln(1-f(x)) +\int\frac{xf'(x)}{1-f(x)}dx.
$$
Can you do the arithmetic to simplify and integrate now? It may also help at some point to substitute $y = x/\sigma_T$ to simplify things...

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I still wonder how to figure out the integration on the right side? Could you give me some hints?

Comment: @Ivy_End what does the integrand look like after the arithmetic is complete?